# Split multi-paragraph documents into paragraph-numbered sentences

Tags: regex, perl, nlp, text-segmentation

I have a list of well-parsed, multi-paragraph documents (all paragraphs separated by *\n\n* and sentences separated by ".") that I'd like to split into sentences, together with a number indicating the paragraph number within the document. For example, the (two paragraph) input is:

```
First sentence of the 1st paragraph. Second sentence of the 1st paragraph. \n\n 

First sentence of the 2nd paragraph. Second sentence of the 2nd paragraph. \n\n
```

Ideally the output should be:

```
1 First sentence of the 1st paragraph. 

1 Second sentence of the 1st paragraph. 

2 First sentence of the 2nd paragraph.

2 Second sentence of the 2nd paragraph.
```

I'm familiar with the Lingua::Sentences package in Perl that can split documents into sentences. However it is not compatible with paragraph numbering. As such I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to achieve the above (the documents contains no abbreviations). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Split a paragraph at a time, then add the current paragraph number in front of each sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `Lingua::Sentences`, I think it's an option to manipulate the original output from this module a little bit to get what you need

```perl
use Lingua::Sentence;

my @paragraphs = split /\n{2,}/, $splitter->split($text);

foreach my $index (0..$#paragraphs) {
    my $paragraph = join "\n\n", map { $index+1 . " $_" } 
        split /\n/, $paragraphs[$index];
    print "$paragraph\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually each paragraph in the document sits on one line, so is there any way to just output the line number instead?

Comment: I don't know what you mean *line number*. This code snippet gives you the same output as you described.

Comment: Worked fine with minor tweak. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you can rely on period `.` being the delimiter, you can do this:

```
perl -00 -nlwe 'print qq($. $_) for split /(?<=\.)/' yourfile.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-00` sets the input record separator to the empty string, which is paragraph mode.
- `-l` sets the output record separator to the input record separator, which in this case translates to two newlines.

Then we simply split on period with a lookbehind assertion and print the sentences, preceded by the line number.